# Connect Samsung S2 with Microsoft exchange server

Tags: email, exchange

I bought Samsung Galaxy S2. I created new e-mail profile with my credentials and successfully connected with Exchange server. I can read my e-mail messages, but when I try to send new e-mail, I get following error:

`Unable to sign or encrypt message. Certificate not installed.`

My company has self issued certificate with .cer extension. What to do ?

Comment: Have a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/how-do-you-import-ca-certificates-onto-an-android-phone

Comment: I will try solutions from given post! Thx