# Adding a self-signed certificate to the trusted list?

Tags: certificates, https

I have my own self-signed SSL certificate for a website I need to keep relatively secure. I've been able to install my client SSL certificate just fine, but I can't seem to install the server's certificate to the Android trusted list, so I always get a warning when trying to access my site in Chrome from the device.

How do I install a PEM or CRT file for a self-signed server certificate?

Comment: Have a look at [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/70123/18559) to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/61540/18559).

Comment: Related: [How do you import CA certificates onto an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4053/16575) / [self-signed certificate install claims success, but android acts as if cert isn't there](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/61540/16575)